# Obtain element id without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to get element id without clicking. I have data inside the divs that needs updating and printing. I can do exactly what I want by clicking the div. The data gets updated, printed, and disappears until the next div shows up. This is jQuery I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.store').click(function(){
        the_id =$(this).attr('id');
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "update.php",
            data:{id:the_id},
            success:function(){
                print_div();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So is there a way to tweak that .click function so that the data automatically gets updated, printed, and disappear without the actual clicking?

Comment: *Something* has to trigger js/jquery.  Your example has two triggers, `click` and `document.ready`.  When do you know you need to get it updated?

Comment: So loop over the elements and make the Ajax calls....

Comment: you can trigger the click from document ready to avoid looping through many elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the divs on document ready. I don't know if this is exactly what you are asking, but this way, you will know the ID of the elements without user interaction.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.store').each(function() {
      var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "update.php",
         data: {
            id: the_id
         },
         success: function() {
            print_div();
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you. However, for some reason, print_div() would not work properly. So I just wrote the function inside the success:function() and it worked exactly how I wanted .

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

JavaScript relies on events - whether timed or created by an interaction (forced or organic) to add methods to the call stack. If you'd like, you can trigger an event (a forced event) using jQuery's trigger method on an event. On the other hand, you can set up a timer using setInterval (a regular action) or setTimeout (a delayed action) to trigger the event. Other than that, you have to rely on the user interaction to trigger events.

You could get clever on what triggers the callback function to the click method - you can look at the user's mouse or scrolling behavior and reload the element or even on some sort of keyboard event. It's really a matter of what will provide the best user experience in your context.

Here is some boilerplate to help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.store').click(storeHandler);
    $('#someOtherElement').on('event', storeHandler);
    setTimeout(storeHandler, 1000);
});

function storeHandler(event) {
    var theElement = $(event.target);   // the event object is very useful
    var theId = theElement.attr('id');
    theElement.fadeOut('slow');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "update.php",
        data:{id:the_id},
        success:function(){
            print_div();
        }
    });
}
```

The goal is to let you replicate the behavior given some event.

Comment: I am still pretty new to javascript and jquery (notice the level of my question). The code did not work for me or I did not had enough knowledge to make it work. Thanks for the help anyways.